# unable to load external page inside DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

Am using following code to load external file inside div

**CODE**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.reveal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.page').load(link);
    });

});
</script>

<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="car.php">Mobile&nbsp;Phones</a>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="tablet.html">Tablets</a></p>
<p class="flaticon-right127"><a class="reveal" href="accessories.html">Mobile&nbsp;Accessories</a></p>

<div class="page"></div>
```

when i click on link external page is opened, but i want to load external file in same page on a div

**car.php**

```
<html>
<body>
external page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing html and body tags from car.php

Comment: i tried, external page doesn't open inside `DIV` its opening car.php

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no errors, it doesn't open file inside did rather it directs to file

Comment: try using car.html instead of car.php

Comment: @sanojlawrence, i have tested its working fine, call full url with http://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned @Anfath Hifans comment it worked in `http://` and later updated my wamp and i no longer get the issue.